# How to initialize unsigned char pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, unsigned-char

I want to initialize an **unsigned char ***  buffer of length 1500 so that I can store values in it from some other sources.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want it on the heap,

`unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[1500];`

if you want it on the stack,

`unsigned char buffer[1500];`

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

The C way of doing this is

```
unsigned char * buffer = ( unsigned char * )malloc( 1500 * sizeof( unsigned char ) );
```

If you want to initialise without junk data created from previous pointers, use calloc, this will initialise the buffer with character 0.

The ( unsigned char * ) in front of malloc is just to type cast it, some compilers complain if this isn't done.

Remember to call free() or delete() when you're done with the pointer if you're using C or C++ respectively, as you're in C++ you can use delete().